# how do ARC in objectiveC changes autorelease usage? (for instance in the description method)

Tags: objective-c, ios5, memory-management

coming from a pre ARC way of thinking of retaining and releasing, i'm trying to wrap my head around ARC in objectiveC.

in the pre ARC days any method returning a newly created instance would use the autorelease pool.

```
- (NSString *)description {
     NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"max size is: %d", maxSize];
     return output;
 }
```

it was the receiver of this newly created instance's job to retain it.

I'm curious. in the ARC world, can you do this?

```
- (NSString *)description {
     NSString *description = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"max size is: %d", maxSize];
     return description;
}
```

is this technically possible? is it logical?
i mean - it feels wrong. it disturbs the retain counting doesn't it?

my question applies also to different getters. for instance:

```
- (NSArray *)items {
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:items];
}
```

can be

```
- (NSArray *)items {
    return [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:items];
}
```

i understood that the ARC adds the retain and release messages for you.
i'd love to understand how this works in these cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either - this is the beauty of ARC. It tracks every object coming from your project and knows if its already autoreleased or not. So yes you can mix. the only gotcha is if you write a library, you need to observe naming conventions, i.e. init returns a retained object.

Comment: in this case, what is the purpose of autorelease factory methods like stringWithFormat? and which approach would you use for these examples?

Comment: They are just historical now - you can use either. Keep in mind that many people are not using ARC, or they have converted older code and don't want to have to go changing all the old methods to one type. Apple did a great job with ARC so that all your old code would mostly work by just removing the retains and releases. I'm using all kinds of methods in my apps in the store with absolutely no problems at all. It may be after a few years Apple deprecates some of the older methods, but then why do it - there is very little cost to keeping them around. Libraries may be glad for both types.

Comment: @David: I thought that if I compile a library function `initWithSomething` then the ARC compiler will create the code to return a retained object, so that naming conventions are also enforced automatically.

Comment: Martin: that's true if the library is also compiled using ARC. It's when you write a library without ARC and call it from an app compiled with ARC that you have to worry about getting the conventions right.

Comment: Do not assume anything when ARC is managing the objects - that's why apple took the retain count message out - they dont want you trying to second guess them. There is no obligation for apple to do anything at any point when ARC is controlling things, other than insure that the object does not go away when it should be in scope and valid. Apple will try to avoid any use of autorelease if it can since that has performance and even memory overhead. If it can its going to create, then release the object in just those two steps.